# if statmaen in php is not showing correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, pgp

the if statement is not showing correct, it is always showing true even is is wrong.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `namemap` WHERE `info_hash`=='{$_GET['info_hash']}'";
if ( $sql == true )
{errorexit(`error`);
}
```

Comment: Query should be `$sql ="SELECT * FROM namemap WHERE info_hash = '{$_GET['info_hash']}'";` use single = in mysql

Comment: Where is query execution?

Comment: it is same result with ` $sql ="SELECT * FROM namemap WHERE info_hash = '{$_GET['info_hash']}'"; `

Comment: Where is mysql_query or mysqli_query????

Comment: Where is execution??

Comment: `$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$db_table`")
$sql ="SELECT * FROM namemap WHERE info_hash = '{$_GET['info_hash']}'";
if ( $sql == true )
{
  errorexit('error');
 } `

Comment: Can u explain which query r u using.

Comment: i have a table named "namemap" with all info_hash and will just allow info_hash who is exit in namemap. do you need see the mysql table for namedmap?

Comment: Use this `if ( mysql_query($sql) )
{errorexit(`error`);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $sql variable is just a string, you never execute a query which I assume you wish to do. A string always evaluates to true.

Comment: $query = @mysql_query("SELECT info_hash FROM namemap where info_hash = {$_GET['info_hash']}");
$result = @mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) 
 {
   errorexit('error');
  }  it is still same